# Double square braces like these ⟦exp⟧?

Tags: braces

How do I create mathematical equation double square braces like these ⟦exp⟧ in latex? I failed to find it on google (I created these using word 2010 equation editor). I would like these to be of adjustable height like regular braces if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look here, and you should be able to quickly find what you are looking for: Exact duplicate of [How to look up a math symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol)

Comment: @Alan: Agree, with the proviso that it took me three goes at drawing the symbol before it came up with the right answer.  _Detexify_ ought to have a "wait until I've finished drawing" option.

Comment: @Andrew I use detexify on my phone, so it waits for me.  But generally I find it faster to look things up in the Comprehensive Symbols guide.

Comment: @Andrew: If you keep drawing it reaccesses the image. It came up in my first attempt. Ok, I got `[` after I finished the first part was finished but it jumped to the correct one when I was finished.

Comment: Thanks for all these wonderful suggestion, I will look them up next time :)

Comment: @Martin: Yes, but it did seem to get confused.  Might just have been my connection.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
...
$\llbracket a+b\rrbracket$
```

You find hundreds of symbols in the "Comprehensive LaTeX List of Symbols" which is on CTAN and, possibly, also on your system (`texdoc symbols`).

Comment: In this modern "internet age", it's useful to point people in the direction of detexify as well as the list of symbols.

Comment: @Andrew: you're probably right, I keep forgetting "detexify". However this resource doesn't suggest `\llbracket` for ⟦, but only `\textlbrackdbl` :(

Comment: It shows `\llbracket`, but not always depending how I draw it.

Comment: egreg: I agree that it's not always perfect - see my comment on the main question!  But one thing that helps is us "training" it (which I did, once it had found the right symbol).